# Is there a verb that means "play along"?

Tags: word-request

> "You look like Barney!" he joked around.
>
> "Arrgh, I am a dinosaur!" she played along.

Is there a verb that means "play along"? I am wondering if there's a single-word verb that means exactly "play along" as in "I decided to play along after my friend decided to make fun of me and call me Barney". I can't think of a single word like that, but I am thinking there might be a word I don't know that might fit the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the word **humour** (US **humor**) for which [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/humour) has

> **humour**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Comply with the wishes of (someone) in order to keep them content, however unreasonable such wishes might be.
>   *But we humoured him, since he spoke our sort of language.*

---

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/humor) has

> **humor** verb
>   **1** : to soothe or content (someone) by indulgence : to comply with the temperament or inclinations of
>   *The only way to get along with him is to humor him.*

---

So it could be

> "You look like Barney!" he joked around.
>   "Arrgh, I am a dinosaur!" she humoured him.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of the word 'cooperate?'

> I decided to cooperate after my friend decided to make fun of me and call me Barney

Comment: But cooperate is completely different than "play along" and also I am not even sure if that makes any sense.

Comment: @yocu *Cooperate* is perfectly good as far as I'm concerned. It's at least as similar to *play along* as is *humour*. *I refused to **(play along / cooperate)** with their plan.*